# Use API v2 to work with Customer Group Prices

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, group-price

Does anyone know a way to write and read the Customer Group Prices with API v2?
We are using a tool to integrate our financial software with Magento. Each customer has a different agreed price for products in Dynamics GP and we need to match this price in Magento. This way, when a Customer logs into the Magento site, their agreed price will be displayed in all simple products.

Answer (score 7):

I've done this for importing group prices with SOAPv2 for Magento CE 1.7.0.2 some time ago and wrote a a (german) [blogpost](http://www.webguys.de/magento/adventskalender/turchen-11-gruppenpreise-uber-die-soap-v2-api/) about this (Google translate might help).
I added the important parts with an english explanation here and hope this helps you getting started.

Basically you need to rewrite the `catalog/product_api_v2` model and extend the `_prepareDataForSave` method.

**Create a new module**

In my example it's Avoe_Catalog:

In `Avoe/Catalog/etc/config.xml` rewrite the Product API:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Avoe_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Avoe_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <avoecatalog>
                <class>Avoe_Catalog_Model</class>
            </avoecatalog>

            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_api_v2>Avoe_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2</product_api_v2>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Avoe/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php:

copy the `_prepareDataForSave` method from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2` to your new Api model:

```
class Avoe_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2 extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2 {

   protected function _prepareDataForSave ($product, $productData) {

      ...

     if (property_exists($productData, 'tier_price')) {
     ...
     }

     //add the following code

     if (property_exists($productData, 'group_price')) {
         $groupPrices = Mage::getModel('avoecatalog/product_attribute_groupprice_api_V2')
             ->prepareGroupPrices($product, $productData->group_price);
         $product->setData("group_price", $groupPrices);
     }

   }

}
```

Create the following file:

`Avoe/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Groupprice/Api/V2.php` copied from `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Tierprice/Api/V2.php`:

In this copied file, I've replaced all `$tierPrices` with `$groupPrices` and updated checks with needed options (cust_group, price, website_id).

```
class Avoe_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Groupprice_Api_V2 extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Api_Resource
{
    /**
     *  Prepare group prices for save
     *
     *  @param      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     *  @param      array $groupPrices
     *  @return     array
     */
    public function prepareGroupPrices($product, $groupPrices = null)
    {
        if (!is_array($groupPrices)) {
            return null;
        }

        $updateValue = array();

        foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice1) {
            $groupPrice = unserialize($groupPrice1);

            if (!is_array($groupPrice)
                || !isset($groupPrice["cust_group"])
                || !isset($groupPrice["price"])) {
                $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Invalid Group Prices'));
            }

            if (!isset($groupPrice["website_id"]) || $groupPrice["website_id"] == 'all') {
                $groupPrice["website_id"] = 0;
            } else {
                try {
                    $groupPrice["website_id"] = Mage::app()->getWebsite($groupPrice["website"])->getId();
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    $groupPrice["website_id"] = 0;
                }
            }

            if (intval($groupPrice["website_id"]) > 0 && !in_array($groupPrice["website_id"], $product->getWebsiteIds())) {
                $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Invalid group prices. The product is not associated to the requested website.'));
            }

            if (!isset($groupPrice["cust_group"])) {
                $groupPrice["cust_group"] = '0';
            }

            if ($groupPrice["cust_group"] == 'all') {
                $groupPrice["cust_group"] = '0';
            }

            $updateValue[] = array(
                'website_id' => $groupPrice["website_id"],
                'cust_group' => $groupPrice["cust_group"],
                'price'      => $groupPrice["price"],
                'delete'     => $groupPrice["delete"] 
            );

        }

        return $updateValue;
    }
}
```

**SOAPv2 API call**

You can insert group prices via SOAPv2 then the following way:

```
$newProductData = new stdClass();
$additionalAttrs = array();

$gp = array(
    "0" => array (
            "website_id" => "0",
            "cust_group" => "1",
            "price" => "11.11",
            "delete" => "1"
        ),
    "1" => array (
            "website_id" => "0",
            "cust_group" => "0",
            "price" => "12.12"
        )
    );

$gp = array("key" => "group_price", "value" => array(serialize($gp[0]),serialize($gp[1])));

$additionalAttrs['multi_data'][] = $gp;
$newProductData->additional_attributes = $additionalAttrs;

$result = $client->catalogProductUpdate($sessionId,$prodSku,$newProductData,"","sku");
```

Comment: This sounds wonderful. I'm running Magento CE 1.9.1.0

Comment: I created the config.xml, create the new API model, and replaced "tierPrices" with "groupPrices" in the V2 file.
I cannot write to the fields though. 
Should the groupPrices be displayed in the wsdl?

Comment: I've updated my answer above with the code from Avoe_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Groupprice_Api_V2. No, the group prices will not show up in the WSDL. They are part of the catalogProductUpdateRequestParam as productData option (typens:catalogProductCreateEntity). catalogProductCreateEntity contains the additional_attributes option where the group_price is set to.

Comment: Is it possible to add the group_price to WSDL as tier_price is done? 
I see that @massimilianoarceri did something similar here <http://stackoverflow.com/a/24576576/3005408>

Comment: Sure, it's a different approach that needs getting more work done but it's also very transparent.

Comment: As "config.xml", I have to put "<global>" inside "<config>" as below to avoid errors like "Uncaught SoapFault exception: Duplicate website group price customer group." `<config>
    <modules>
      <Avoe_Catalog>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
      </Avoe_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <models>
        <avoecatalog>
          <class>Avoe_Catalog_Model</class>
        </avoecatalog>
        <catalog>
          <rewrite>
            <product_api_v2>Avoe_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2</product_api_v2>
          </rewrite>
        </catalog>
      </models>
    </global>
  </config>`

Comment: Actually there's no difference to what I have posted above? Despite the full config.xml declaration which I've updated.