# Allowing external developers access to webservices

Tags: magento-1.8, web-services

I am working on a project where we need to enable webservices within Magento so an external developer can work with them so that they can add, remove & update products.

Having read the docs it seems that either SOAPv2 or REST is the way forward however the item I wanted to confirm is this. If I have extensions installed that affect the catalogue for example hide product x from a,b & c groups I presume I will need to write a wrapper for the the official Magento webservice so that the extension data can also be added, removed or updated. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: You will most likely need to add these custom features on your own to extend the webservice functionality.

While it depends on your attributes types on how you need to transfer the data, you can get an idea with this link which shows how to extend the SOAP API for customer group prices:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58171/231

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://www.codepetals.com/setup-your-magento-store-for-integration-with-mobile-app-or-an-erp/

It may help you with creation of API and its User and Roles.

Comment: It would be cool if you could add the most important information from this link here just in case it is not available any more at a later time. Thanks!